# How to identify last iteration in while(true) loop in c#

Tags: c#, while-loop

This is C# code..

```
while (true)
{                
    DateTime dtNext = start.AddMinutes(duration);
    if (start > end || dtNext > end)
        break;

    if (start < DateTime.Parse("12:00 PM"))
    {
        if (!doneMornHeader)
        {
            Label head = new Label();
            head.Text = string.Format(header, "Morning");
            this.Timediv.Controls.Add(head);
            doneMornHeader = true;
        }

        morning = start.ToShortTimeString() + "-" + dtNext.ToShortTimeString();

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.ID = "ImpLabel" + k;
        lbl.Text = morning;

        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "ImpCheckbox" + k;

        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='task low'>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='desc'>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='title'>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(lbl);
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch span5 pull-right' data-on='success'>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(cb);
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
        this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));            
        k++;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!doneAfternoonHeader)
        {
                    Label head = new Label();
                    head.Text = string.Format(header1, "Afternoon");
                    this.Timediv.Controls.Add(head);
                    doneAfternoonHeader = true;
        }
         afternon = start.ToShortTimeString() + "-" + dtNext.ToShortTimeString();
         Label lbl1 = new Label();
         lbl1.ID = "ImpLabel" + k;
         lbl1.Text = afternon;
         CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
         cb1.ID = "ImpCheckbox" + k;
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='task medium'>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='desc'>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='title'>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(lbl1);
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch span5 pull-right' data-on='success'>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(cb1);
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
         k++;
      }
     start = dtNext;                
}
```

Now I want to find out the Last iteration of that while loop...

In the Last iteration I want to change

```
this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='task low'>"));
```

to

```
this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='task low last'>"));
```

in both if and else..

i.e. In both morning session and afternoon session..

How can find last iteration?

Comment: You need to define "last".

Comment: Just check what the value in the next iteration would be. If it's your end, you know that this is the last iteration.

Comment: Abstract all of that logic into a function, which takes the string which will change as an argument. Put an invocation of the function with `"<div class='task low'>"` as an argument inside the body of your loop, as you have now, and put an invocation with `"<div class='task low last'>"` as an argument after the loop.

Comment: 'While(true)' is generally a very bad construct! The conditions should be properly specified in the loop condition.

Comment: Also, there's no sense in using `while(true)` and then putting a conditional break inside the body of the loop. You should move the loop condition to the `while(...)`.

Comment: Why is this a while (true)? you have a condition, it's start > end || dtNext > end, why don't you use that as your while condition?

Comment: I have edited, pls see.....

Comment: @CodeCaster, would u give me any code????

Answer (score 1):

This is your last iteration:

```
if (start > end || dtNext > end)
break;
```

In addition, right before you're getting into the last iteration, you can introduce some small check:

```
DateTime tempDtNext = start.AddMinutes(duration);
var tempStart = tempDtNext;
var isGoingToEnd = (tempStart > end || tempDtNext > end);
this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("<div class='task low {0}'>", isGoingToEnd ? "last" : string.Empty));
```

Comment: Right before: `this.Timediv.Controls.Add`

Comment: I put this code in both if and else bloks, but It did not work. it doesn't gives 'task low last'. It always gives 'task low' only

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't add the control before the `break`? This appears to be where you are exiting the loop:

```
while(true)
{
     if (start > end || dtNext > end)
     {
         //add control
         this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='task low last'>"));
         break;
     }

    //do stuff..
}
```

Also, why bother with `while(true)` if you have a condition which can terminate the loop?

It should be:

```
while(start < end || dtNext < end)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: If you need to add the control in either condition then it should be outside of both. If it needs to be on the last iteration, then it should be in the check that you do before breaking, the above meets both criteria.